# where to place the foreground() method

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to run a service which gives notification, if available every few minutes. Since the service will get destroyed after few hours, I thought of making it foreground service. But if I do so, it shows two notification. One is notification column(Thats what I need and got). Another one on Ongoing column which shows icon that work go at all. Its really annoying. The notification code goes like this

Notification.java

```
n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Update", "new update arrived", pIntent);
n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
startForeground(2233,n);
n.flags |=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NM.notify(id,n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have an ongoing notification to use a foreground so that the user can know it's active.  You could schedule an alarm with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to start up your service when needed instead of keeping it alive the whole time.  You can then do your check at whatever interval you'd like, and your notification will stay alive even if the service closes.

Comment: OK. Thanks I'll do it. But could you explain why it is showing so. It might help me in future.

Comment: when you move a service to the foreground, you get a persistent notification while it's in the foreground.  when you present that notification through notification manager, it's a separate notification.